# How to avoid login if already logged in in angular js

Tags: angularjs

In my application i am maintaining URLs to separate the customers like

myapp.localhost.com/#/customer1
myapp.localhost.com/#/customer2

Now say customer1 logged in. Then in same browser but in other tab customer2 is entering his url. At this point i want to avoid customer2 to login and when he hit url i want to give customer1 url again as logged in.

I have used below code.

```
    .factory('authService', function ($rootScope, $state, $auth, $location,     $stateParams) {
    return {
        isLoggedin: function () {
            console.log($auth.isAuthenticated());
            if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                if($rootScope.currentUser.accessLevel == '1')
                {
                    $rootScope.currentUser = null;
                    $location.path('/admin');
                }
                else
                {
                    $rootScope.currentUser = null;
                    //$state.go('customer',{'customerTag' : localStorage.getItem('customerTag')});
                    $location.path("/"+localStorage.getItem('customerTag'));
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
})


 .run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $location, $auth) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    });
    });
```

Please suggest the solution

Comment: To Clarify - you want user1 to login, user2 uses a new tab and you want them to get the login screen. When user1 goes back to their tab they are still logged in while user2 still has the login screen? IF that is the case, consider saving your auth token in memory, or in the localStorage but with unique keys to keep them separate.

Comment: No. If user 1 hitting url in one tab for customer1 and login. Then same user in another tab hitting url for customer2 now in this case i don't want him to show the login screen for customer2 i want to show him customer1's screen with already login

Answer (score 1):

You can put a 'resolve' key in your router configuration ensuring that a logged user will be redirected to admin panel or any other place. Like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '/templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        resolve: {
            canLogin : ['$q', 'authService', function ($q, authService) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                if (authService.isLoggedin()) {
                    // redirect user to admin panel or any other place
                    $location.path('/admin');
                    // location.path("/"+localStorage.getItem('customerTag'))


                    deferred.reject();
                }
                else {
                    deferred.resolve();
                }

                return deferred.promise;
            }]
        }
    })
```

Tip: avoid to change the storage in a method like isLoggedin. Probaly is better update the storage according to the return of this method.